# не получается установить pyaudio на macbook на m1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

выдает ошибку в терминале.

при вводе pip3 install pyaudio.

до это вводил:

```
brew remove portaudio
brew install portaudio
```

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y6/x97lz5316h5bcwq3fb4ys5rm0000gn/T/pip-install-sl6vxnlq/pyaudio_62d7dc5a89e94b978a6f8671407dda39/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/y6/x97lz5316h5bcwq3fb4ys5rm0000gn/T/pip-install-sl6vxnlq/pyaudio_62d7dc5a89e94b978a6f8671407dda39/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/y6/x97lz5316h5bcwq3fb4ys5rm0000gn/T/pip-record-earasy_q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyaudio
         cwd: /private/var/folders/y6/x97lz5316h5bcwq3fb4ys5rm0000gn/T/pip-install-sl6vxnlq/pyaudio_62d7dc5a89e94b978a6f8671407dda39/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
    #include "portaudio.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y6/x97lz5316h5bcwq3fb4ys5rm0000gn/T/pip-install-sl6vxnlq/pyaudio_62d7dc5a89e94b978a6f8671407dda39/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/y6/x97lz5316h5bcwq3fb4ys5rm0000gn/T/pip-install-sl6vxnlq/pyaudio_62d7dc5a89e94b978a6f8671407dda39/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/y6/x97lz5316h5bcwq3fb4ys5rm0000gn/T/pip-record-earasy_q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyaudio Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

требуется компиляция и g++ не установлен. Предлагаю поискать альтернативы, к примеру soundevice

Comment: speech_recognition требует pyaudio

Comment: Вероятно он работает с фреймами, на что способен и соунддевайс. Темболее sounddevice используется единственныйм оффлайн распозновальщиком голоса vosk.